# From result set Values are not getting but able to retrieve meta data

Tags: sql, jdbc

Below is the code I am trying. Resultset Meta data is getting but values or not displaying it is showing thread pool error.

```
         ResultSet rs = pst.executeQuery();
         out.println("<P ALIGN='center'><TABLE BORDER=1>");
         ResultSetMetaData rsmd = rs.getMetaData();
         int columnCount = rsmd.getColumnCount();
         // table header
         out.println("<TR>");
         for (int i = 0; i < columnCount; i++) {
           out.println("<TH>" + rsmd.getColumnLabel(i + 1) + "</TH>");
           }
         out.println("</TR>");
         // the data
         while (rs.next()) {

          out.println("<TR>");
          for (int i = 0; i < columnCount; i++) {
            out.println("<TD>" + rs.getString(i + 1) + "</TD>");
            }
          out.println("</TR>");
          }
         conn.close();
```

Comment: Can you post the query pls? Maybe it's not returning Strings, but another type.

Comment: Please add the complete error message

Comment: I solved it. Thank you, I think the application doesn't loaded perfectly